Show Server Status in Splunk
I want to create a Splunk table that shows server status.
I have a query that returns the server and it's type, currently.
But, I can't figure out how to show it's status, I.e. whether it's OK or if there's an error.
I need to match anything that resembles an '200' http status with "OK", and anything with an error message with "ERROR"
| eval status=case( 
                  match(_raw, "HTTP/1.1\" 200"), "OK", 
                  match(_raw, "ERROR"), "ERROR", 
                  true(), "Unknown") 

However, I am not sure how to show this in my table.
I am only interested in select few servers that are hardcoded in the query.
Here's what I have so far, which shows the server name, and node type.
index=app 
| WHERE host IN ("dgp4ds2345", "dgp4ds2346", "dgp4ds2347", "dgp4ds2348", "dgp4ds2349")
| eval node_type=case(
                  host IN ("dgp4ds2345", "dgp4ds2346", "dgp4ds2347"), "processor",
                  host IN ("dgp4ds2348", "dgp4ds2349"), "storage")  
| table server, type, primary

Here's what I wany my table to look like, ultimately:



server
type
primary




dgp4ds2345
processor
OK


dgp4ds2487
processor
OK


dgp4ds2289
storage
OK




You have the code.  Does it work if you put the pieces together?  If not, what you get?
index=app host IN ("dgp4ds2345", "dgp4ds2346", "dgp4ds2347", "dgp4ds2348", "dgp4ds2349")
| eval type=case(
                  host IN ("dgp4ds2345", "dgp4ds2346", "dgp4ds2347"), "processor",
                  host IN ("dgp4ds2348", "dgp4ds2349"), "storage")  
| eval primary=case( 
                  match(_raw, "HTTP/1.1\" 200"), "OK", 
                  match(_raw, "ERROR"), "ERROR", 
                  true(), "Unknown")
| rename host as server
| table server, type, primary


Thanks! To take it a step further, how would I can I match mutiple conditions for the ERROR. For example, anything with status code from 400-599. And anything with "ERROR", "WARNING", etc.

It's not clear what you mean by "multiple conditions".  You can add more clauses to the case function or you can use AND and/or OR to test for multiple conditions in the same clause as in ... case ( (status > 400 AND status <=599) OR match(_raw, "ERROR"), "ERROR", ...
